# Getting "Identifier expected"

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is the exercise I'm doing:

> Write an application that creates a two-dimensional array with 5 rows and
>   4 columns. Fill the array with random numbers between the 0 and 100. Search the
>   array for the smallest value. Display the array and the indexes where the smallest
>   value is stored.

Here is where I am so far and can use some help. Currently I'm getting two errors (Identifier expected) on the bold line or the line enclosed with **. Also I'm not sure If I'm headed in the right direction. Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated. I'm a business major taking C# as an elective :(

```
Random random = new Random();
int smallest = 100;
int x = 0, y = 0;

int[,] numbers = { 
    {random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100),   random.Next(0,100)}, 
    {random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
    {random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
    {random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)}, 
    {random.Next(1,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100)} 
};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i, j] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = numbers[i, j];
            x = i;
            y = j;
        }
        **Console.WriteLine("Element({0},{1})={2}"... i, j, numbers[i, j]);**
    }
    Console.Write("\n\n smallest number is {0} at element [{1}, {2}]", smallest, x, y);
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: Are the three dots in the `WriteLine` for real, or just an indication that you have abbreviated some longer string?

Comment: Use a loop to initialize the array! If you have to write the same thing 20 times, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Console.WriteLine("Element({0},{1})={2})", i, j, numbers[i, j]);
```